# problem with display of quantity on a cart html page using js

Tags: javascript, html, product-quantity

thank you for your previous help, now the toal quantity works perfectly. i have tried to aplly the same principle with the total price but it displays "nan" (" price += parseInt(monPanier[i].price);"). before adding this line, the total price diplayed was only one copy per item even eg there was two black items, 3 red items and 4 yellow, it was considered as total price one black + one red + one yellow.
Thank you for your help.

```js
 let asynCompteur = 0;
    let quantity = 0;
    let price = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < monPanier.length; i++) {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/products/' + monPanier[i].id)/*appel de l'api*/
        .then((reponse) => reponse.json())
        .then((data) => { 
            /*asynCompteur pour réguler l'itération*/
            asynCompteur = asynCompteur + 1;              
            //J'ajoute le prix et la quantité
            quantity += parseInt(monPanier[i].quantity);                price += data.price;
            console.log('prix', asynCompteur, price, quantity);
            price += parseInt(monPanier[i].price);
            console.log(typeof monPanier[i].quantity);
            if (asynCompteur === monPanier.length) {
                document.querySelector("#totalQuantity").innerText = quantity;
                document.querySelector("#totalPrice").innerText = price; 
            }
```

Comment: Try to use `parseInt(asynCompteur) + 1` when you add

Comment: try ```quantity += parseInt(monPanier[i].quantity,10);```

Comment: As far as I can see, the only way this could be a string is when `monPanier[i].quantity` is a string.  What does `console.log(typeof monPanier[i].quantity)` prints?

Comment: Clearly `monPanier[i].quantity` is type string. Conversion to integer is necessary since Javascript string concatenation operator `+` is the same as, and takes precedence over, integer addition. As already mentioned `parseInt` is one solution. Another is the [unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) `quantity += +monPanier[i].quantity;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Addition not working in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243782/addition-not-working-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you all but what daes "10" means for "quantity += parseInt(monPanier[i].quantity,10);"?

Answer (score 0):

it works partially. The quantity is updated correctly and follow the changes of the cart.So, the display of total quantity is correct.But... strangely, the total price consider only one of each item, it means: ie black item (2 times), yellow item (3 times), red item (2 times), total quantity displayd: 7 (correct), total price: incorrect(it displays total price of one black item + one yellow item + one red item.
Thank you for your precious help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).